# How do I fix it. 50(10/100 + 1). Expect result = 55. But i got 55.000000001 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have

```
var x = 100;
var y = 10;
var b = 10 /100 + 1;
var z = b*50
```

Expect z = 55. But I got z = 55.0000000001. I don't know why. 
How do I fix it in Javascript.
Thanks

Comment: What does `x` and `y` have to do with the rest of the code?

Comment: That's the nature of Javascript as we know it. You either live with it, parsing, rounding, formatting time and time again, or use a numeric (math) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
z = parseInt(z);
```

It will treat z as int.

Answer (score 0):

Use `toFixed` for digits after the decimal point. Default is 0.

```
var x = 100;
var y = 10;
var b = 10 /100 + 1;
var z = b*50;

alert(z.toFixed(0));
alert(z.toFixed()); //both are same
```

For more reference : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp